# How to access component via ActivatedRouteSnapshot?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, access-control, role-based-access-control

**Use case**

Guard components using `CanActivate` of [Angular Guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

**Sample Route**

```js
{
 path: "my-path",
 component: MyComponent,
 canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
```

**MyComponent as sample component**

```js
export class MyComponent {
  // Dependency required by AuthGuard to allow/deny access
  // Each component declares resources that it guards, along with access levels
  static guardedResources = [
    {"user_profile" : {"access" : "write"}},
    {"posts" : {"access" : "read"}}
  ];
}
```

**AuthGuard code**

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  // Component resolution happens at runtime via route.component
  
  // Common logic to read component's guardedResources and match them against
  // user's access privileges lies here
}
```

When I try to access the component property via `route.component.guardedResources`, it throws

```js
error TS2339: Property 'guardedResources' does not exist on type 'string | Type<any>'.
      Property 'guardedResources' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Doing `console.log(route.component)` shows my component's body on console, so I'm fairly confident that I can resolve this by typecasting `route.component` appropriately to get through to `guardedResources`.

**Possible solution**

Step 1 - Abstract `guardedResources` in a base class and override that property in derived components.

Step 2 - Typecast `route.component` to this base class so that `guardedResources` is available as a valid property.

I think I am missing some basic knowledge of Angular or TypeScript here. Could someone please point me to relevant links/docs that I could refer?

Answer (score 0):

The `route.component` holds the type of the `component` as `string` or `Type<any>`, so if you want to get the static `guardedResources` from it, you have to cast it to `MyComponent` type before that, like the following:

```js
// To make sure that the component type is `MyComponent`
if (route.component === MyComponent) {
  // Cast the type of route.component` to the type of `MyComponent` to access its static variables:
  const guardedResources = (route.component as typeof MyComponent).guardedResources;

  // Do the other stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar answer for this issue on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679726/accessing-component-of-the-activatedroute-in-the-canactivate-guard). Another way to handle this, might be a constant handling the `paths` with the inner object of what you are trying to match:

```
 export const ROLES = {
   'my-path': {
     {'user_profile' : {'access' : 'write'}},
     {'posts': {'access' : 'read'}}
   }
 }
```

Then in your guard you can simply check the path of the `route` and do the necessary logic, without the need of casting a component.

I think it might be cleaner that way.